# How and when should I connect to database with serverless?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aws-lambda, serverless

I new to aws lambda and serverless.

Serverless provides me one file called `handler.js`.

How can I use the mongo database in this file?

In regular nodejs application I was connect to the mongo database then after the connection is good I was continue the application and launch the server. something like this:

```
(async() => {
   await mongoose.connect(...);
   const app = import('./app');
   app.listen(....);
})();
```

But when I use serverless the application already launched. when to make the connection to db should be?

Answer (score 2):

Create sperate mongoconnection.js to maintain mongo db connection and import it in handler.js

mongoconnection.js

```
"use strict";
// Import dependency.
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
// Connection string to the database
const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
// Validate that the database connection string has been configured.
if (!uri) {
  throw new Error(
    'The MONGODB_URI environment variable must be configured with the connection string ' +
      'to the database.'
  );
}
// Cached connection promise
let cachedPromise = null;
// Function for connecting to MongoDB, returning a new or cached database connection
module.exports.connectToDatabase = async function connectToDatabase() {
  if (!cachedPromise) {
    // If no connection promise is cached, create a new one. We cache the promise instead
    // of the connection itself to prevent race conditions where connect is called more than
    // once. The promise will resolve only once.
    // Node.js driver docs can be found at http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/.
    cachedPromise =
      MongoClient.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true,  useUnifiedTopology: true });
  }
  // await on the promise. This resolves only once.
  const client = await cachedPromise;
  return client;
}
```

handler.js

```
// Import dependency.
const { connectToDatabase } = require('./connect-to-mongodb');
// Handler
module.exports.handler = async function(event, context) {
  // Get a MongoClient.
  const client = await connectToDatabase();
  // Use the connection to return the name of the connected database.
  return client.db().databaseName;
}
```

Please refer below link for more details
https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/best-practices-connecting-to-aws-lambda/

Comment: although this is the best practices, it seems kind of workaround because when you have the request then initial the database or any other resource. is there a function I can provide to hook the server initial event?